# AWS Lambda not showing APIGateway trigger in console UI, but it works

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

The strange thing is that the connection is working as expected, but the UI does not accurately reflect the state.

Below is a screenshot of my Lambda UI. You can see that it has no trigger attached to it.

[image: aws lambda function]

However, I have connected an APIGateway REST resource to the Lambda correctly, I just did it from the APIGateway side, rather than the Lambda side.

[image: api gateway]

Is there a way to "refresh" the lambda UI to show this trigger? I cannot remove and re-add the trigger though the lambda UI, because when I do, it uses the wrong APIGateway path, which I need to be `/twilio/interact` (It creates a `/interact` resource).

Answer (score 2):

The issue was the "Resource-based policy" on the Lambda. The source arn of that policy must be set to that of the APIGateway resource (redacted above). When that source arn is set, that's how the lambda UI knows which specific trigger is attached.